# Помогите с регуляркой (убрать лишние пробелы)

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть регулярное выражение, которое удаляет теги, но если в тексте идут несколько тегов подряд, то появляются лишние пробелы.
Как убрать эти лишние пробелы?

```
var test = string.replace(/(#\w+)/g, '');
```

[image: Скриншот]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var string = 'Как    убрать  #эти лишние      пробелы?';
var test = string.replace(/(#[\wа-яё]+)/gi, '').replace(/[ ]+/g, ' ');
console.log(test);
```

Comment: Магия какая-то, работает! Спасибо, мил человек. :з

Comment: @JohnDoe: новогоднее чудо :)

Comment: Да! 
Эх, хочу надеяться, что у Вас оно случится так же скоро) 
Еще раз большое спасибо)